# Slick-carousel error unslick is not a function

Tags: jquery, slick.js

As you can see, there are 8 blocks 4 on top and 4 from below.

I need to that the slider worked in mobile version.Like in  [**there**](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GdexQW?editors=1010)

Also if you look at this link attentively you should see that this code don't work in onload.

I'll take this code made some changes and it had to work but did.I'm getting a bunch of bugs in the console.

Error: **Cannot read property 'unslick' of undefined**

I have tried to change from

```
 $(".container-slick").unslick("unslick");
```

to

```
$(".container-slick").slick({
   settings:"unslick"
});
```

But it didn't work.

Please help.

Here the my [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/PeLyGr)

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 768){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 1
        });
    }
    else{
      $(".container-slick").slick("unslick");
    }
  });
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 768){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 1
        });
    }
    else{
      $(".container-slick").unslick("unslick");
    }
  });
```

```css
.projects_block {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.project_block {
    width: 23%;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects_block container-slick no-padding">
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Saint Petersburg Philharmonic Orchestra</div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Grand Hall Music </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Hand-made art & design workshop</div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Saint Petersburg Philharmonic Orchestra</div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Grand Hall Music </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
    <div class="project_name">Hand-made art & design workshop</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-->As on Window Load if width is less than 768 px then only we are applying slick js no need to unslick it because it will fire only width is less than 768px 
--> Also on resize Jquery There is an error of $(".container-slick").unslick("unslick"); 
--> So your new script will be like this

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).on('load', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 768){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 1
        });
    }
    else{
    }
  });
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 768){
     $('.container-slick').slick({
          centerMode: true,
          infinite: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          speed: 200,
          slidesToShow: 1
        });
    }
    else{
      $(".container-slick").slick("unslick");
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: one second i will check

Comment: sorry but it did not help .unslick error I remove (also give you +1 ) but slider did not work